# Why image not saved in thumb folder on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading, laravel-5.6

I use laravel 5.6

My method to upload image like this :

```
public function uploadImage($file) {
    if($file) {
        $fileName = str_random(40) . '.' . $file->guessClientExtension();
    }
    $destinationPath = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'product';
    if(!File::exists($destinationPath)) {
        File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, 0755, true);
    }
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    return $fileName;
}
```

The code works. If the method run, it will save a file in product folder

But I want to add a logic. If the image success saved in product folder, then it will make a folder thumb in folder product

I try add this code below `$file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);` like this :

```
$destinationPathThumb = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'product' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'thumb';
if(!File::exists($destinationPathThumb)) {
    File::makeDirectory($destinationPathThumb, 0755, true);
}
$file->move($destinationPathThumb, $fileName);
```

Then I run my method, the images uploaded successfully in the product folder. But the image was not uploaded successfully in the thumbs folder. Seems the code : `$file->move($destinationPathThumb, $fileName);` is not working

Maybe my logic code is still wrong

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need to copy the image because while sending image through request, it can be moved to a single location only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the file since multiple move of a single image will not give what you want.

You can do it like this,

```
$destinationPathThumb = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' .   DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'product' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'thumb';
if(!File::exists($destinationPathThumb)) {
    File::makeDirectory($destinationPathThumb, 0755, true);
}

Storage::copy($destinationPath. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName , $destinationPathThumb . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: There exist error like this : `File not found at path: home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/product`

Comment: @SuccessMan I've updated my answer try this one. Older one have path to only directory but you need full path of file.

Comment: Thanks. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961920/how-do-i-upload-files-on-2-folders-at-once-in-one-method-on-the-laravel. Maybe you can help me

Comment: Okay I'll see that as well.