# How do I upload files on 2 folders at once in one method on the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, image-uploading, laravel-5.6

I use laravel 5.6

I want to upload files on 2 folders at once. So if the image uploaded successfully in the product folder, I want the image uploaded in the thumbs folder as well

I try like this :

```
public function uploadImage($file)   
{
    if($file) {
        $fileName = str_random(40) . '.' . $file->guessClientExtension();
    }

    $destinationPath = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'product';

    if(!File::exists($destinationPath)) {
        File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, 0755, true);
    }

    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    $destinationPathThumb = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'product' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'thumb';

    if(!File::exists($destinationPathThumb)) {
        File::makeDirectory($destinationPathThumb, 0755, true);
    }

    $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());  
    $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
    $image_resize->save($destinationPathThumb . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);

    return $fileName;
}
```

If the code run, it just success to upload in the product folder. It did not upload in the thumbs folder

There exist error like this :

> message   Unable to find file (/tmp/phpUSxbEJ).
>
> exception Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException

I try run this code :

```
public function uploadImage($file) 
{
    if($file) {
        $fileName = str_random(40) . '.' . $file->guessClientExtension();
    }
    $destinationPathThumb = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'product' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'thumb';

    if(!File::exists($destinationPathThumb)) {
        File::makeDirectory($destinationPathThumb, 0755, true);
    }
    $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());  
    $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
    $image_resize->save($destinationPathThumb . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);
    return $fileName;
}
```

So I remove code to upload in product folder. I try it and it works. It success upload on the thumbs folder

So I think in one process, it only upload in one folder

Is there any other way to upload on 2 folders?

Comment: After you save `$file` then use `Storage::get()` to retrieve the `SAVED` file, instead of the `temporary $file`

Comment: @NikolaGavric Try to answer this question with code. Let me be clearer

Comment: @SuccessMan where is your post method with http request ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam On the controller. My code above is placed in the repositories

Comment: Eh okay nice way to do so, you are using design patterns ? did you got solution ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes, Of course. I'm still have not find a solution. Answer below still have error

Comment: To be precise, I just want to know which pattern ? Any way what's the error ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Look at this : https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching. Try to see my comment below. The error like that

Comment: You did `copy` after store file.

Comment: @Jaydeep Mor Seems it cannot use `copy`. Because I want to resize it first

Answer (score 1):

You first upload the `temporary file` which will be removed once you save it on your disk, thats why u can't reuse it, instead of reusing it, you fetch the saved image and do resizing on it and save it with a different name:

```
public function uploadImage($file) 
{
...
$file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
//$file here doesn't exist anymore, hence it can't be read
...
$uploadedFile = Storage::get($destinationPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
$image_resize = Image::make($uploadedFile);  
$image_resize->resize(300, 300);
$image_resize->save($destinationPathThumb . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);

return $fileName;
}
```

Comment: There exist error like this : `Class 'App\Repositories\Storage' not found`

Comment: If you take a minute to read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files then you can see that you have to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

Comment: There is still exist error. The error : `message /home/vagrant/code/my-app/storage/app/public/product/gckx3YQrbc8CnKMaXjlpjy9FnejYpbjKetMHXKGN.jpeg`.
`exception Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution

I try like this :

```
$file = $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

It works